# Converting date to position on the X axis returns out-of-bounds float

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib

I'm trying to get the X position of a date on my X axis (made of `datetime`s).

My X axis is the dates between December 2016 and January 2018:

```
axA.set_xlim(datetime(2016, 12, 1), datetime(2018, 1, 30))
print(axA.get_xlim())

output >> (17136.0, 17561.0)
```

I would like to place an annotation on the 12th of October, and for that I need to know the position of that date on the axis. I read the docs and tried doing it in two different ways:

```
release = datetime(2017, 10, 12)
print(mdates.date2num(release))
print(mdates.datestr2num('2017-10-12'))

output >> 736614.0
output >> 736614.0
```

The value returned by `date2num` and `datestr2num` is not within the range of my X axis (`(17136.0, 17561.0)`, see above), despite the date provided clearly being within the range.

Minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime


def get_dataframe():
    values = [12, 16, 20]
    dates = [
        datetime(2017, 12, 24),
        datetime(2017, 12, 23),
        datetime(2017, 12, 22)
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(data={'date': dates, 'value': values})
    df = df.set_index(['date']).sort_index()

    return df


def plot(dataA):
    fig, axA = plt.subplots()
    dataA.plot(ax=axA)

    axA.set_xlim(datetime(2016, 12, 1), datetime(2018, 1, 30))
    release = datetime(2017, 10, 12)

    print(mdates.date2num(release))
    print(mdates.datestr2num('2017-10-12'))
    print(axA.get_xlim())


df = get_dataframe()
plot(df)
plt.show()
```

*NB: I just noticed that setting the `xlim` before plotting the data appears to return the date in the given range, but then my graph starts in January year 3986!*

I'm using:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.3
$ pip freeze | grep matplot
matplotlib==2.1.1
```

Comment: Why not use the date as the x coordinate? You can do it like so: `plt.text(datetime(2017, 10, 12), 16, "Some text")`. This places a text box with _Some text_ at 12 October at y coordinate 16.